# Почему не запускается Vue.js приложение?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

Есть приложение, которое строилось на Webpack, конфиги которого брались из `vue init webpack` несколько месяцев назад.

Сейчас решил скопировать директорию `src` старого приложения в новое, которое я создал сегодня командой `vue init webpack`.

После я добавил командой `yarn add` все пакеты, которое требовало приложение (основывался на ошибках в консоле при запуске).

И теперь, когда я запускаю приложение командой `yarn dev`, я получаю непонятную ошибку. При выполнении команды `yarn build` тоже все падает.

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
  "build": "node build/build.js"
},
```

Ошибка:

```
yarn run v1.5.1
$ webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js
 67% building modules 1167/1212 modules 45 active ...mmon/components/Common/Notice.vuenode(62769,0x7000082c6000) malloc: *** error for object 0x109fa0180: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit signal: SIGABRT
Command: sh
Arguments: -c webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js
Directory: /Users/colibri/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/vuejs-app
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/colibri/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projects/vuejs-app/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**ДОБАВЛЕНИЕ**

Я сразу не заметил этого, но сейчас, когда повторно создал приложение, обнаружил следующую проблему, которая никак не влияет на запуск только что созданного приложения.

Когда приложение сгенерировалось, далее автоматически запускается выполнение команды:

```
eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs --fix
```

На что возвращается ошибка:

```
/Users/colibri/Desktop/vue-webpack/my-project/test/unit/specs/HelloWorld.spec.js
  4:1  error  'describe' is not defined  no-undef
  5:3  error  'it' is not defined        no-undef
  8:5  error  'expect' is not defined    no-undef

✖ 3 problems (3 errors, 0 warnings)

error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs --fix
Directory: /Users/colibri/Desktop/vue-webpack/my-project
Output:
".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/colibri/Desktop/vue-webpack/my-project/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

И эта ошибка в целом похожа на ту, что я получаю в основном приложении.

Что же все-таки не так? Почему только что созданное приложение падает с такой же ошибкой, что и в основном приложении?